# ASP.NET MVC4 Bundling scripts not finding scripts in sub folders - why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-optimization

In my ASP.NET MVC4 application's RegisterBundles method, I create the following Script bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/whatever")
    .Include("~/Scripts/whatever1.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/Whatever/whatever2.js"));
```

So, "whatever1.js" is directly under the Scripts folder, whilst "whatever2.js" is in a subfolder under Scripts.

When I run my code (in debug) then this loads the "whatever1.js" script file, but not the one in the subfolder.

This is a big site and for sanity's sake it's proved useful up to now to segregate the script files under separate folders.

So the question is: is this bad practice on my part, or is the bundling mechanism just not there yet (or have I simply messed up the syntax)?

Thanks in advance

Griff

Comment: try running in 'Non-debug' mode

Comment: What are your actually JS files called? The bundler ignores certain Javascript files.

Comment: Groan - went for a re-boot and it now works.  Apologies for not having thought of that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Problem went away after a re-boot.